# Save files with modification time of last change in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

In notepad++, many times I have hundreds of tabs and leave unsaved text files for weeks before I finally save them. When I do, I would like to save them not with the current timestamp, but with the timestamp of when I actually last modified them (i.e. the timestamp of the appropriate backup file in `c:\Documents and Settings\<USER>\Appplication Data\Notepad++\backup\`. Is it possible in Notepad++? How?

Comment: By unsaved files do you mean existing files (e.g. `effects.js`) or new files? (e.g. `new44`). Or both?  Also, are you open to any coding in order to achieve requested behavior (e.g. writing your N++ plugin)?

Comment: @miroxlav: actually, both :-) in fact, both variants will be in the backup directory with the right timestamp so it shouldn't be a problem. And I would prefer not to code of course (but writing a script would be much easier than having to compile and build something)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is exactly what plugins are for. I am not sure about existing plugin for this, but you should be able to achieve your goal with relatively simple plugin. Create a plugin which will create a command "Save with last modified timestamp" (Edit: ...and map it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> originally used for Save).

When invoked:

1. Asks for save file name. (It is trivial using standard Windows *FileSaveDialog*. Almost a copy-paste from N++ source for **Save As...**.)
2. Saves the file into specified location. (Almost a copy-paste as well...)
3. Retrieves last modification timestamp from file backup of that file. (Location of the backup file is known to N++. Once you have the file path, getting the timestamp should be a single API call.)
4. Sets last modification timestamp to file saved in step 2. (Again, should be nothing more than a single API call.)

And you can enjoy timestamp values you expect.

Here are [Plugin Resources](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Plugin_Resources) including [Plugin Development Quck Start Guide](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Plugin_Development_Quick_Start_Guide) and [Technical information on coding a plugin](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Plugin_Development). Based on your StackOverflow profile, this should not be very diffictult thing for you. Checking the resources, plugins can be developed in 4-5 various programming languages. Perhaps C or C# could suit you the best. Also it is possible you can write the entire thing in Python script. Just install [N++ Python Script plugin](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/) and you can go way of scripting. However, I am not sure whether all necessary N++ internals (e.g. location of backup file) are available for running scripts. If not, you might need to work that around.

Comment: Thanks!! It's great that it can be done using a plugin!!! I thought patch will be necessary. And scripting is great too!! Though I don't know python.... Anyway t would be desirable *not* to create a new command, but to change the behavior of "Save". Because I know myself and I am 100% sure that I will forget not to use save but to use some special new command.... So the best solution is to add a settings option that tells Save to use either current or last modified date as the timestamp. Is that possible in a plugin?

Comment: @Tomas: Your plugin can have options, although not in main Options dialog, but on its own. I believe that modifying Save implemented in core to check value of option set somewhere is not possible without changes in the core. But I think you still *can* create a new command (as described in the answer) and then simply map it to `Ctrl`+`S` which was used for Save. (Using the Keyboard Mapper.) And then hide the toolbar with original Save icon to prevent accidentally clicking it.